# How to refactor useEffect to onlick function

Tags: reactjs, components, refactoring, use-effect

I need to fetch when a user clicking on the submit button but I'm absolutely don't know how to do that:

```
export default function SearchSong() {
    const [topSongs, setTopSongs] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(
            "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search&track=Positions&api_key=a3c9fd095f275f4139c33345e78741ed&format=json"
          );
          const data = await response.json();
          setTopSongs(data);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
        }
      };
      fetchData();
    }, []);
  
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="inner-input">
            <h1 className="search">Search for song:
            <input size="50" type="text"/>
            <button type="submit"></button>
            </h1>
        </div>
        {topSongs?.results?.trackmatches?.track.length &&
          topSongs.results.trackmatches.track.map((datumn) => {
            return (
              <Fragment key={datumn.name}>
                              <h1 className='heading'>{datumn.name}</h1>
              </Fragment>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I can do it with class component, but not functional

Comment: Can you add onSubmit to button and call the `fetchData`? why do you need `useEffect`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I absolutely agree with @Shimi who commented. Why would you need `useEffect`?

Try to do something similar:

```
<button onClick={fetchData} >Fetch</button>
```

Define `fetchData` in `SearchSong`.

example:

```
export default function SearchSong() {
    const [topSongs, setTopSongs] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(
            "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search&track=Positions&api_key=a3c9fd095f275f4139c33345e78741ed&format=json"
          );
          const data = await response.json();
          setTopSongs(data);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
        }
      };
  
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="inner-input">
            <h1 className="search">Search for song:
            </h1>
            <input size="50" type="text"/>
            <button onClick={fetchData} >Fetch</button>
        </div>
        {topSongs?.results?.trackmatches?.track.length &&
          topSongs.results.trackmatches.track.map((datumn) => {
            return (
              <Fragment key={datumn.name}>
                              <h1 className='heading'>{datumn.name}</h1>
              </Fragment>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new state called `fetchSongs` which will be toggled when `Fetch Songs` button is pressed, and add that state as a dependency to the `useEffect`, so each time you click on `Fetch Songs` button, the state of `fetchSongs` changes which in turn triggers `useEffect`.

The answer given by @sonkatamas is also a nice one. But it will not run the fetch functionality when component is first loaded, in this case `useEffect` comes in handy.

```js
export default function SearchSong() {
    const [topSongs, setTopSongs] = useState([]);
    const [fetchSongs, setFetchSongs] = useState(false);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(
            "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search&track=Positions&api_key=a3c9fd095f275f4139c33345e78741ed&format=json"
          );
          const data = await response.json();
          setTopSongs(data);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
        }
      };
      fetchData();
    }, [fetchSongs]);
  
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="inner-input">
            <h1 className="search">Search for song:
            <input size="50" type="text"/>
            <button onClick={()=> setFetchSongs(!fetchSongs)}>Fetch Songs</button>
            </h1>
        </div>
        {topSongs?.results?.trackmatches?.track.length &&
          topSongs.results.trackmatches.track.map((datumn) => {
            return (
              <Fragment key={datumn.name}>
                              <h1 className='heading'>{datumn.name}</h1>
              </Fragment>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```